# How to update MySQL table based on 3 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following four MySQL tables

```
Region
RegionId

City
CityId
RegionId

Hotel
HotelId
CityId

HotelRegion
HotelId
RegionId
```

I'm struggling to write a UPDATE statement to update the City table's RegionId field from data in the HotelRegion table.

Basically how can I update the City table with the correct RegionId where the HotelId in the HotelRegion table matches the City table's CityId.

This is my UPDATE statement at the moment

```
UPDATE City c
SET c.RegionId = 
(SELECT DISTINCT(HotelRegion.RegionId) FROM HotelRegion 
INNER JOIN Hotel ON Hotel.HotelID = HotelRegion.HotelID
INNER JOIN City ON City.CityId = Hotel.CityId
WHERE City.CityId = 1233)
WHERE c.CityId = 1233
```

The error message I get is You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause.
Please let me know if you need any more information to help answer my question

Comment: Would appreciate some pointers based on my question rather than a vague response.

Comment: Your table structures have me confused.  If the Hotel table links to the City table through the City ID and the City ID table has a link to the region, why does the HOTELREGION table exist? Doesnt that duplicate the information that is alreay in the HOTEL table?

Comment: Because the RegionId is NULL at the moment.  So I need to get the data from HotelRegion which I have e.g I know which Region and City a Hotel is in.  But the system doesn't know what Region a City is in.

Comment: I had assumed that the HotelRegion.RegionID and the City.RegionID were both references to Region.RegionID.

Comment: I wished that was the case.  Basically this data comes from a external source and on processing it I will run this UPDATE routine, when it works ;)

Comment: So, to understand this. The REGION table has no data, but thats okay since we arent going to do anything with it anyway. You recieve information from another source that populates the HOTEL and HOTELREGION tables. You want to take that information and populate the City table.

Comment: All tables have data, except City.RegionId field which is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After must testing, I managed to get the following update query out to work correctly

```
UPDATE City
INNER JOIN Hotel ON City.CityId = Hotel.CityId
INNER JOIN HotelRegion ON Hotel.HotelId = HotelRegion.HotelId
SET City.RegionId = HotelRegion.RegionId
WHERE City.CityId = 1223
AND Hotel.CityId = 1223
```